# Keyword starts loop and ends loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I just started learning py today and I have a question with a discord bot im making.
So I want to have a bot that spams a certain message every second or so. I have this so far.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Logged in as:")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    channel = bot.get_channel(854067941632901163)
    print("Channel is:")
    print(channel) #Prints None
    get_price.start()


@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def get_price():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(854067941632901163)
    print("Channel is:")
    print(channel) #Prints None
    await channel.send('Test')

@get_price.before_loop
async def before ():
    print("Before done.")

bot.run('token')
```

Every 3 seconds, it spams a message. I want it so I can say like !spam and it will trigger the bot to spam whatever message is there, and to stop the bot it would be like !stopspam. I've tried taking other bits of codes but none of them have worked. Again yes I an very new so take it easy on me lol.

Comment: I am SO tired of people asking "what is wrong with my discord.py? Also I'm new to Python." You have to understand that discord.py is not anywhere close to a beginner Python project, and it can be complicated at times, even for Python experts like myself. Try something simple. Maybe learn Tkinter or Turtle. Maybe make a Reddit meme scraper. But hold off on a year or two until you're actually good with Python to make a bot.

Answer (score 0):

Just make two commands that will use `start()` and `cancel()`. Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    loop.start()


@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    loop.cancel()


@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def loop():
    # your loop code here
```

Comment: thanks man now i know for the future heres a kiss

Comment: If this helped you, please mark this answer as a solution.